# Can you add an "AND field = value" to any SOQL query?

Tags: sql, salesforce, soql

Assuming the query looks like this:

```
SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE <some filter here>
```

and I want to add this:

```
AND field = value
```

In other words: if a query ends with the WHERE (doesn't have other sections/statements like "LIMIT" etc.), can you ALWAYS add an AND and have it not break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understood the question and I think that's not the best way to proceed.
Anyway, I think it's always possibile. Pay attention to have a "some filter here" which does not end with a ";" and leave a blank space before the content you would like to add. Make sure the attributes you use are compatible with the selected table.

Comment: Thanks. It's not me who made it this way, I worded the question wrong. I was just figuring out whether or not it can be broken somehow.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are queries where adding AND field=value to the end of them will result in a query that is invalid. The easiest example is one that has an OR clause it in.

`select name from Contact where name like 'a%' or name like 'z%'`

Adding the and clause gives

`select name from Contact where name like 'a%' or name like 'z%' AND email=null`

which when you run it will give a malformed query error.

```
MALFORMED_QUERY: 
name like 'a%' or name like 'z%' AND email=null
                                ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:64
unexpected token: AND
```

Comment: I think the queries this will be done to all have redundant parantheses like this: ```SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE (name like 'a%' or name like 'z%')``` That eliminates this problem. Do you think that's everything that can go wrong?